Issue with Patching Object Value to Angular FormControl in ngAfterViewInit
I'm working on an Angular form where I need to patch an object to a FormControl in ngAfterViewInit. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to patch an object. Here's a simplified version of my code:
My HTML Code
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field fxFlex.lt-sm="auto">
      <mat-label>Action Type</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="actionType">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of actionTypeFilter" [value]="s">
          {{ s.Name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>

My TypeScript Code
actionTypeFilter = [
  {Name: 'All', Key: "All"},
  {Name: 'Allow', Key: 300201},
  {Name: 'Deny', Key: 300202},
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    actionType: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.filterFormControls.actionType.patchValue({Name: 'All', Key: "All"});
}

get filterFormControls() { return this.filterForm.controls; }

The Problem:
When I attempt to patch an object value to the FormControl in ngAfterViewInit, it doesn't work. However, if I modify the HTML to use the Key as the value, like this:
<mat-option *ngFor="let s of actionTypeFilter" [value]="s.Key"> {{ s.Name }} </mat-option>
this.filterFormControls.actionType.patchValue("All");
It works correctly, but the issue is when I console the value of actionType it will give only the Key value but i want full object of selected item.
I want to patch the entire object (e.g., {Name: 'All', Key: 'All'}) to the FormControl while keeping the original HTML structure. How can I achieve this?

You can use compareWith to perform the equality check for the select using the key, so we can select the entire object using this method.
compareFn(o1: any, o2: any) {
  return o1.Key === o2.Key;
}


Full Code:
HTML:
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Action Type</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="actionType" [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of actionTypeFilter" [value]="s">
          {{ s.Name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>

{{filterForm.value | json}}

TS:
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {
  Validators,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  filterForm = new FormGroup<any>({});
  actionTypeFilter = [
    { Name: 'All', Key: 'All' },
    { Name: 'Allow', Key: 300201 },
    { Name: 'Deny', Key: 300202 },
  ];
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      actionType: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.filterFormControls.actionType.patchValue({ Name: 'All', Key: 'All' });
  }

  compareFn(o1: any, o2: any) {
    return o1.Key === o2.Key;
  }

  get filterFormControls() {
    return this.filterForm.controls;
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Great to hear that it's working fine!
Thanks @Naren Murli

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Use setTimeout to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.filterFormControls.actionType.patchValue({Name: 'All', Key: "All"});
  });
}

Please try to settime out because some time they take initial time

yes, I tried using setTimeout but is is not working.

Have you used AfterViewInit lifecycle
